# Could someone briefly differentiate a java library, a class, and a package

Tags: java

I'm documenting my project which is a really simple Android application and I'm getting rather confused about the three.

Is what you import on Java the library? Is an API a library? If so, does that mean that Android is a library?

Comment: A library is a multi-volume (printed) encyclopedia, a package is a volume in the encyclopedia, and a class is an article in the volume.  (But, alas, I suppose you've never seen an old-fashioned printed encyclopedia.)

Comment: @kw4nta -- Not intended to be funny -- accurate.

Answer (score 2):

`library` : A collection of one or more packages will be called library. 
`package` : A group of classes will contribute a package. 
`class` : <strike>A compiled java which accomplish an atomic functionality of its own.</strike>  A class is a construct that is used to create instances of itself
In `java`, you could either import a `package` or `class` itself. Yes, `API` could be called library using which we could built our own system/application. `Android` is a `platform` and not `library`. But `android SDK` could be called library instead which has API for talking to device.

Comment: nope, a class is definitely not compiled java. a '.class' file is compiled java.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my answer. Used the same terminology as in wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

A `library` is a software that contains implementations of any kind of thing software can do '.dll' files in windows, '.jar' files in java. Libraries usually provide one or more `API`s (Application Programming Interface), that allow you to use the application. To an API belong the public `Class`es and `Interface`s in the Library (or the functions in C).

Android is an operating system. It provides libraries. These provide APIs.

EDIT: forgot packages:

`packages` are java's way of grouping classes and interfaces.

Another EDIT: classes are part of Object Oriented Languages. They define what Object's have (properties) and do (methods).

`.class` files are compiled java code.

Answer (score 0):

A Class is the code construct that allows to create instances of itself or perform operations with the methods it includes. It's the basic unit of your programm.

A package if a collection of Classes that interact and offer some special functionality/help to accomplish a specific task.

A Library is a compound of Classes and Documentation that help in the development of software, often including several packages.

Answer (score 0):

**class:** A `byte-code` file produced by compiling the `.java` file using `javac` (Java compiler).Further read by `JIT` to **convert it into** `runtime machine level executable code`.

**package:** `Collection of classes`, In java **mainly** all the packages are according to their functionality.

**library:** Consider its a a `collection of packages`, `documentation` etc.